# What may cause differences in displaing http content on server?

Tags: php, apache

```
<section>
<?php echo(file_get_contents('http://server_address'));?>
</section><script>
    <!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--
    $("ul").html('http://server_address');
 //--><!]]>
</script>
```

What may cause that first server gets me the content of the link, the second displayed only text "http://server_address". Both servers are Apache2.

Comment: Because.... that's what you're telling it to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you use `file_get_contents` in PHP, that is actually doing what you need. The second use you just output the text. So your program is doing exactly what you wrote.

If I understood correct what you need is to output content from the link into `ul` element. This can be done l

```
<section>
<?php echo(file_get_contents('http://server_address'));?>
<!-- save content to variable, escaping quote chars -->
<?php $content = addslashes(file_get_contents('http://server_address')); ?>
</section><script>
    <!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--
    $("ul").html('<?php echo $content; ?>');
 //--><!]]>
</script>
```